# Reading text files with multiprocessing slower than without

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I have some text files that I need to read with Python. The text files keep an array of floats only (ie no strings) and the size of the array is 2000-by-2000. I tried to use the `multiprocessing` package but for some reason it now runs slower. The times I have on my pc for the code attached below are

- Multi thread:  73.89 secs
- Single thread: 60.47 secs

What am I doing wrong here, is there a way to speed up this task? My pc is powered by an Intel Core i7 processor and in real life I have several hundreds of these text files, 600 or even more.

```
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime


def read_from_disk(full_path):
    print('%s reading %s' % (datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'), full_path))
    out = np.genfromtxt(full_path, delimiter=',')
    return out

def make_single_path(n):
    return r"./dump/%d.csv" % n

def save_flatfiles(n):
    for i in range(n):
        temp = np.random.random((2000, 2000))
        _path = os.path.join('.', 'dump', str(i)+'.csv')
        np.savetxt(_path, temp, delimiter=',')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # make some text files
    n = 10
    save_flatfiles(n)

    # list with the paths to the text files
    file_list = [make_single_path(d) for d in range(n)]

    pool = ThreadPool(8)
    start = time.time()
    results = pool.map(read_from_disk, file_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print('finished multi thread in %s' % (time.time()-start))

    start = time.time()
    for d in file_list:
        out = read_from_disk(d)
    print('finished single thread in %s' % (time.time() - start))
    print('Done')
```

Comment: It seems you are only testing with 10 files. Please note that Multiprocessing has some significant startup time. What happens if you have 100 or 1000 files?

Comment: Using multiprocessing always includes overhead for: spawnig threads, waiting threads, joining results etc. Most of the time for IO-Operation the slow thing is the IO-access with opening / closing files. If something performs better using mutltithreading is data/situation dependent - seems yours is not (in this test case).

Comment: @quamrana, thanks, just edited my post. I have quite a few hundreds of these files, not just 10 or 20

Comment: So, what happened when you tested with 100 or 1000 files? I mean use `n = 100` or `n = 1000` in the test code you posted. You could have `save_flatfiles()` generate smaller files for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are using `multiprocessing.dummy` which replicates the API of multiprocessing but actually it is a wrapper around the threading module.**

So, basically you are using `Threads` instead of `Process`. And `threads` in python are not useful( Due to GIL) when you want to perform computational tasks.

So Replace:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
```

**With:**

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
```

*I've tried running your code on my machine having a `i5 processor`, it finished execution in 45 seconds. so i would say that's a big improvement.*

Hope this clears your understanding.

Comment: Are you sure that reading or writing files is a *computational* task?

Comment: @SergeBallesta It's not just about reading or writing the file, the OP is using numpy to actually perform the computational task which is **Loading the data from storage and then numpy is mapping this data to the `ndarray`**. Don't you think it's computational?

Comment: What I mean is that in this kind of task, most of the time is spent in disk io. And having many processes competing for the disk may just slower the whole operation.

Comment: Actually I don't think so because i've tried running the code using  both `Threads` and `Process` and guess what there is a huge time efficiency improvement while using processes.

Comment: Then it would be interesting that you post the times (use timeit to measure them) for single threaded, multi-threaded and multi processes versions.

Comment: Big shout out to Shubham! Many thanks, you nailed it. With your change, my code (for `n=10`) runs in 20.8 secs. When I set `n=100` then the time without `multiprocessing` is 594secs  vs 197secs when `mulitprocessing` is used

Comment: @ShubhamSharma, to your knowledge please, is there any case where `multiprocessing.dummy` would be a better choice than `multiprocessing`?

Comment: @Aenaon As @SergeBallesta also mentioned `multiprocessing.dummy` would be a better choice when your task is dependent more on **I/O** than that of **CPU intensive work**. So, you have to weight the use case according to your requirements.